# An appbar appears after realise build

Tags: flutter

I just generate the apk of my flutter app, when I launch it an appbar (the black appbar) appears on top of my app screen as it shown on the image:

[image]
I didn't know from where it comes.

Comment: Post code please

Comment: My flutter's code is clean works fine before generate apk, that happens after the generate maybe something changes in the Android folder. I have to create another project and add my futter code there, thank you.

Comment: Well, we can't help you without seeing what you are doing, always post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to following code in the below file solved my issue.

File : android/pp/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ic_launcher_background">#f88004</color>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It seems like `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` is main